# C# Comet 'pull' application to receive google finance prices?

Tags: c#, html, ajax, comet

Is it possible to use WebRequest in C# to write a small application which mimicks what a google finance webpage does, when it automatically updates the graph and price when viewing a stock?

I just wish to have a client waiting and then be sent 'pushed' a new price from the google server?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do that.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx

Comment: That looks really useful! Would you be able to explain to me, where in that section i would need to enter the google (i think its called JSON) details whic hare mentioned here:

http://cometdaily.com/2008/06/04/google-finance-comet/

Comment: hang on, isnt that link about continuously asking the server for data, rather than setting up an open stream for the server to just send stuff to the client?

Comment: I don't think Google are providing access to this in a purely data-centric way. I think they probably pay a financial data provider for that data so wouldn't then just forward it on for free.